# Can I create a PID file for systemd services?

Tags: systemd, pid, affinity

I have two systemd services that run after system start . I need to set CPU affinity for these 2 services but I can't do that manually because after every reboot or service restart , PID changes.

Is there any way that these 2 systemd services can create PID files when they start so that I can use the value of that PID file in another script to set CPU affinity for that service ?

This is one of the services for example :

```
[Unit]
Description=public 1 run
After=network.target

[Service]
User=steam
Group=steam
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/server @public1 start
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If you know how I can achieve this either via PID file or any other method , please let me know .

Comment: Have you tried [setting it in the unit file](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_monitoring_and_updating_the_kernel/assembly_configuring-cpu-affinity-and-numa-policies-using-systemd_managing-monitoring-and-updating-the-kernel)?

Comment: @vidarlo I tried but got the following : systemctl set-property public1 CPUAffinity=0,1,2,3,4,5
Failed to set unit properties on public1.service: Cannot set property CPUAffinity, or unknown property.

Answer (score 0):

Setting CPUAffinity=0 inside the systemd service file worked :

```
[Unit]
Description=public 1 run
After=network.target

[Service]
User=steam
Group=steam
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/server @public1 start
CPUAffinity=0
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```